# Apex - Create WorkOrderLineItem fieldset

Tags: metadata-api, fieldsets, dynamic-apex

We have created multiple fieldset for various custom and standard objects using Apex but new "WorkOrderLineItem" object related to "Services" seems be different.

Here is sample code which creates FieldSet for both PricebookEntry and WorkOrderLineItem, but "Product2.Description is only added to PricebookEntry fieldset.

```
 set<string> createFieldSet = new set<string>{'PricebookEntry', 'WorkOrderLineItem'};
map<string, list<string>> mapFieldSet_FieldNames;
map<string, string> mapFieldSet_Description; 

//Store field set name and description
mapFieldSet_Description =  new map<string, string>();   
mapFieldSet_Description.put('FieldsToDisplay', 'Choose fields to display'); 

//Store field set name and field names
mapFieldSet_FieldNames =  new map<string, list<string>>();      
mapFieldSet_FieldNames.put('FieldsToDisplay1', new list<string>{'Product2.Description'});             


        Try{
            Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> globalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
            //Instantiate MetaDataService class
            MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
            service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
            service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();       

            //Metadata API has limit of 10 for each call. Create variables to store more than 10 
            list<MetadataService.Metadata> createMetadata = new list<MetadataService.Metadata>();


            //Create metadata    
            MetadataService.FieldSet fieldSet;
            MetadataService.FieldSetItem myFields;
            MetadataService.CustomField customField;                        

            //Create PBE and WOI field set
            for(string sObj : createFieldSet){
                for(string fieldSetName : mapFieldSet_Description.keySet()){
                    try{
                        if(globalDescribeMap.containsKey(sObj)) {
                            //Continue if field set does not exists already
                            if(!globalDescribeMap.get(sObj).getDescribe().fieldSets.getMap().containsKey(namespace + fieldSetName)){  
                                fieldSet = new MetadataService.FieldSet();
                                fieldSet.fullName = sObj + '.' + fieldSetName;
                                fieldSet.label = fieldSetName;
                                fieldSet.description = mapFieldSet_Description.get(fieldSetName);
                                fieldSet.displayedFields = new List<MetadataService.FieldSetItem>();

                                //Add fields to this field set
                                for(string fieldName : mapFieldSet_FieldNames.get(fieldSetName)){                       
                                    myFields = new MetadataService.FieldSetItem();
                                    myFields.field = fieldName;
                                    fieldSet.displayedFields.add(myFields);
                                }
                                system.debug(sObj + ' ' + fieldSet);
                                //Add field set to the list
                                createMetadata.add(fieldSet);                  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        system.debug(e.getMessage());
                        system.debug(sObj + ' not enabled');
                    }
                }
            }                
        if(createMetadata.size()>0)
            service.createMetadata(createMetadata); 
    }catch(Exception e){
    system.debug(e.getMessage());}
```

Then I thought Probably "Product2.Description" is not valid path for WorkOrderLineItem, so I created fieldset in UI, added the field and ran below apex.

```
for(Schema.FieldSetMember field : Schema.SObjectType.WorkOrderLineItem.fieldSets.FieldsToDisplay1.getFields())
{
   system.debug('field ' + field);
   system.debug('field path ' + field.getFieldPath());   
}
```

And in debug log, I could see same path that I provided in Apex. What am I missing?

```
DEBUG|field Schema.FieldSetMember[
   getDbRequired=false;
   getFieldPath=Product2.Description;
   getLabel=Item Family;getRequired=false;
   getType=PICKLIST;
]
```

Comment: Although you're using metadata api, you may find taking a look at this will be helpful: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_methods

Comment: hi @crmprogdev , thanks for the comment but I am not sure "DescribeFieldResult" is going to help in create metadata (in this case feildset)

Comment: Any thoughts on this? It seems to be happening for OrderItem object as well. In both cases metadata API does not understand Product2 path if added as FieldItem